# output MOSS 2010 configuration for documentation purposes

Tags: configuration, command-line-interface, documentation, sharepoint-2010

When writing documentations about a system I usually can use the sysinfo command on the command line to output most configurations and Hardware Specs. This saves a lot of time and makes the job of documenting a system (a little bit) easier. Now I would like to know if the same is possible for MOSS 2010?

NOTE: Yes, I have written down the configurations I made in MOSS2010!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Microsoft had you in mind when they created MOSS 2010.  Check out the following script.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff645391.aspx

Comment: Great stuff! Thanx for not letting me down ;)